# Need Colorpad equivalent for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, color-picker

There is a program that I have been using for about 10 years now: http://matthieu.bizland.com/ colorpad. Unfortunately, it is only supported by Windows however, I need it for Mac OSX. Is there an equivalent? BTW, this is a desktop application not a browser extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hues](http://giantcomet.com/hues) (formerly Spot Color).

Comment: I should clarify that colorpad lets you simply point at any place on your screen to get the exact color of that portion of your screen.

Comment: Use DigitalColor Meter, then. It's in /Applications/Utilities.

Comment: Uhm...this is on topic....if you would have asked,  I would have explained how it relates. But instead,  you closed the question...pft

Comment: @syn4K: *I* didn't close the question.